# Prolog: append is failing inside loop

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog code:

```
my_function(A):-
   my_function(A,[],1).

my_function(A,List,Num):-
   Num_new is Num+1,
   generateL(O,S,L),
   write(L),nl,
   %append(L,List,List_New),
   (  Num_new < 20 -> my_function(A,List_New,Num_new)  ).
```

Which is working. It loops through 19 times, calls `generateL` which generates a new term `L` which I print to the screen.

I now want on each iteration to append `L` to a list `List` to create a new list `List_New` which is then passed through in the recursive loop as `List` such that in the next iteration this is the list that `L` is again appended to.

I have attempted to do this by writing the `append` statement which is commented out above. The problem is that this statement is failing - I believe because `List_New` is not seen as a variable, but rather as a pre-existing list, thus append is testing whether `List_New` is indeed `L` and `List` appended together, as opposed to creating a new list `List_New`.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you describe your problem *independently* of your concrete implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If L is a term, you can replace:

```
 %append(L,List,List_New),
```

with:

```
 List_New=[L|List],
```

Comment: of course! so simple :) Believe it or not, I had actually tried List_New=[L,List] which didn't work because it kept on creating a list inside a list, inside a list, and so on. But I didn't think of this. Thanks!